# chromeOptions responsive mode show device frame argument?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, responsive, chrome-options, mobile-emulator

Is there an argument so I can setup the chromeOptions to show the device Frame in responsive mode

here is what I use so far:

```
    HashMap<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", deviceName);

    ChromeOptions chromeOpts = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOpts.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

    chromeOpts.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    chromeOpts.addArguments("--enable-web-app-frame");
    chromeOpts.addArguments("--enable-mobile-emulation");
```

Aslo where can I find the list of the deviceName values supported?